# How to list files starting with "a" or "c" from /etc.

Tags: ls, wildcards

I tried `ls /etc/[ac]*` but it shows directories starting with *a* or *c*, and their entire contents, not the files starting with "**a**" or "**c**".

Comment: _directories_ are one of many types of _files_. What types of files are you interested in (regular, symlink, device, pipe, socket...)?

Comment: It is unclear whether you by "directory" are talking about the _contents_ of the directories, or about the directory names themselves. The command that you show would list the contents of directories that matches the pattern, with `ls -d /etc/[ac]*` you would not get the contents of matching directories, but would still see the directory names. It is unclear whether this is what you want or if you would want to avoid even listing the directory names.

Answer (score 27):

To avoid listing the contents of directories, you can:

```
ls -d /etc/[ac]*
```

That will list the directory *names* along with ordinary file names starting with `a` or `c`.

For completeness, a solution not involving `find` might be:

```
ls -ld /etc/[ac]* | grep ^- | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9
```

Comment: My initial reading of the question also made `ls -d` seem appropriate, but it seems that the original question specifies that no directories should be listed, regardless of expansion or non-expansion.

Comment: `ls -ld /etc/[ac]* | grep ^- | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f9` don't parse `ls`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Well, the relevance of that advice depends on whether one needs this solution to work once, or forever. If only once, then parsing `ls` is fair game in my opinion.

Comment: He does have a point. While names in `/etc` are very likely to be sane, a simple space will break the `ls` approach since the field numbers will change.  +1 for `ls -ld` though.

Comment: You also need to fix the locale (`LC_ALL=C`), date is not guaranteed to have 3 fields in other locales.

Answer (score 9):

Recursively:

```
find /etc -type f -name '[ac]*'
```

If you require non-recursion, you can do this portably:

```
find /etc/. ! -name . -prune -type f -name '[ac]*'
```

Or this, non-portably (GNU or a recent BSD find):

```
find /etc -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '[ac]*'
```

If you want to do this case insensitively, use `-iname` instead of `-name`.

Comment: Note that `-type f` is for _regular files_. If instead you need non-directory files, replace with `! -type d` (or `! -xtype d` with GNU `find` if you also want to  exclude symlinks to directories).

Answer (score 3):

If you want both directorys (not directory's contents) and files, you can use `printf` bultin:

```
printf "%s\n" [ac]*
```

Example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" [te]*
examples.desktop
teamviewer_linux.deb
test.php
test.txt
```

Comment: How will this avoid directories, as requested in the question?

Comment: Oh, my misreading. I think OP want directory but not its contents.

Comment: Sorry about that edit, completely misread.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl /etc/[ac]*(.)
```

Would list the *regular* files (as in `-type f` in `find`) listed in `/etc` whose name starts with `a` or `c`. The `(xxx)` part at the end of a glob is a zsh-specific feature called globbing qualifier. `.` as a globbing qualifier means *regular file*.

If the glob doesn't match, `zsh` will abort the command. Note that in other Bourne-like shells, if the glob doesn't match, the pattern expands to itself, so `ls -d /etc/[ac]*` could incorrectly list a file called `/etc/[ac]*` if there's no file starting with `a` or `c` in `/etc`.

```
print -rl /etc/[ac]*(^/)
```

would list the files that are *not* of type *directory* and

```
print -rl /etc/[ac]*(-^/)
```

would list the files that are not of type directory after resolving symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this command also,

```
for file in /etc/[ac]*; do echo $file; done | xargs file | awk -v FS=" +" '$2~/directory/ {next;} {print $1}' | sed 's|\/etc\/||g;s/://g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-recursive without `find`:

```
ls -pd /etc/[ac]* | grep -v '/$'
```

the `-p` adds a `/` at the end for directories, which the `grep` filters out. Of course doesn't work for filenames which contain special characters like newlines.

Answer (score 1):

For display files starting with a:

```
ls etc |  grep ^a
```

For displaying files starting with c:

```
ls etc |  grep ^c
```

Comment: this one work for me